# I'm getting ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3072) into shape (5000)

Tags: numpy, vectorization

```
num_test = X.shape[0]
num_train = self.X_train.shape[0]
dists = np.zeros((num_test, num_train))
for i in range(num_test):
    dists[i,:] = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(self.X_train - X[i,:]), axis = 0))
```

I'm getting

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3072) into shape (5000)
```

Shape of `X` is `(500, 3072)`, so shape of `X[i,:]` is `(3072,)`
Shape of `self.X_train` is `(5000, 3072)`, and `dists` is an array of zeroes with dimensions`(num_test, num_train)`.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Did you mean to sum over axis 1 instead? That makes the right hand side the right shape.

Comment: Just did, it works. Thanks I feel dumb now

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?:

```
dists[i,:] = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(self.X_train - X[i,:][None,:]), axis = 0))
```

Comment: @koko Could you please post the error log as well as printing out the shape of two matrices in the equation?

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
dists[i,:] = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(self.X_train - X[i,:]), axis = 0))
```

you need to replace `axis=0` with `axis=1`, since dimension reduction occurs along the axis being summed over.